# Erase vector element from vector of objects by value

Tags: c++, vector

I have a c++ vector of student objects with each object having an ID(string), name (string) and age(int).

```
std::vector<student> myVector;
```

Lets say the vector looks like this

> [{"1", "Tom", 12}, {"2", "David", 10}, {"3", "Adam", 15}, {"4", "Jill", 20}]

Is there any way I can delete an object in the vector using the student Name like:

> `myVector.deleteObjectWithName(David)`

such that my remaining vector is now

> [{"1", "Tom", 12}, {"3", "Adam", 15}, {"4", "Jill", 20}]

Comment: `std::remove_if` is what you need

Comment: This isn't the same question which you marked: that asked about value, while this requires `remove_if`

Comment: Of course, as you asked the question, `std::remove_if` is the answer as pointed out by @DimChtz. But I can imagine that in general you want to look up students by ID, in which case an `std::map` might be a more useful data structure. (Also, why is student ID a string?) {edit} nvm, see you want to delete by name instead of ID. General remarks might still be useful though.

Comment: I have edited the question. I want to delete by name. Student ID is a string because I do not plan to do any arithmetic on it

Comment: But if it is a unique number, making it a numeric datatype still has some advantages, such as the fact that you can quickly compare it to other IDs and can safely use it as keys into an `std::map`.

Agree with the fact that the duplicate is not a duplicate btw.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) is what you need:

```
myVector.erase(std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 
  [](students const& s) { return s.name == "David"; }), myVector.end());
```

Comment: I formatted the output a little bit, and I think there was a missing bracket. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: It is, I missed that bracket, and forgot to recheck it after I noticed that the question was closed